# Typescript version in project is not compatible with typescript version in my computer

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, dependencies, version, conflicting-libraries

## npm resolution error report

While resolving: undefined@undefined
Found: react@18.2.0
node_modules/react
react@"^18.2.0" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer react@"^17.0.0" from react-mde@11.5.0
node_modules/react-mde
react-mde@"*" from the root project

How to solve this problem? Should I downgrade or upgrade typescript version?